# Custom Validation on Address Field

Tags: entities, javascript

In addition to the validation that already takes place using the addressfield module, I'd like to check for (and fix) items like:

- Building to Bldg
- Room to Rm
- Circle to Cir
- Avenue to Ave

Is there a module that would do this?
Is this best done with a custom module or using JavaScript?

Any chance that this module might be helpful?
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript validation because some people can disable JavaScript in the browser and you're validation will fall!

If you want custom validation will be better if you will use additional validation for your form (custom code)

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily bad to use JS validation, but you should never rely on it.